# to print json file in python that json data should reflect in kibana

Tags: python, json

I want to print json data used in this code and that should reflect in kibana

I tried to run program through python3 terminal

```
import string
from typing import Dict, List, Union

import demjson as demjson
import json
import os, json
import traceback
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class ESSend():
    def __init__(self, es_server, index):
        print("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")

    def send_to_data_lake(self, data, index, doctype):
        try:
            es = Elasticsearch(self.es_server)
            dart_response = es.bulk(index=index, doc_type=doctype, body=data)
            print("dart_response = %s", dart_response)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raise

#my json data
data=[{
    "data": [
        {"target": "111111111111111111",
         "build": "OTV5.2.8_BLD6.0_180608",
         "buildorder": 5243000,
         "testType": "animation",
         "total_time": 47.289,
         "avg_fps": 7,
         "memoryConsumed": "545976",
         "timestamp": "2019-02-02",
         "image": "official"
         },
        {
         "target": "2222222222222222222",
         "build": "OTV5.2.8_BLD6.0_180608",
         "buildorder": 5243000,
         "testType": "animation",
         "total_time": 47.289,
         "avg_fps": 7,
         "memoryConsumed": "545976",
         "timestamp": "2019-02-02",
         "image": "official"
         },
        {"target": "33333333333333333333333",
         "build": "OTV5.2.8_BLD6.0_180608",
         "buildorder": 5243000,
         "testType": "animation",
         "total_time": 47.289,
         "avg_fps": 7,
         "memoryConsumed": "545976",
         "timestamp": "2019-02-02",
         "image": "official"
         }
    ]
}]

for post in data['data'] :
    es = ESSend("10.12.133.93", "qualityportal-opentv-graphics-perf")
    es.send_to_data_lake(data, 'qualityportal-opentv-graphics-perf', 'graphics');
    print(post)
    print (post['message'].encode("utf-8"))
print(demjson.encode(data))
```

I want to know whether can I use any list to print data. I think some modification should be done in loop, can anyone help me? I tried for one json data, it was working fine with this code, but I don't know what went wrong in this case.

Comment: So, the problem is?

Comment: I am not able to print that json file

Comment: To print or insert into elastic?

Comment: both i want to print in kibana whole json data

Comment: Output should be like this(the below is output for one json data but i need for more than one json data  ):

dart_response = %s {'_index': 'qualityportal-opentv-graphics-perf', '_type': 'graphics', '_id': 'ec7FGm0BTYjjaRDxJqXG', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 9, '_primary_term': 23}